# Azure IoT Hub and reliable direct methods

Tags: azure-iot-hub

We are working with a scenario where a device can be "unlocked" and we want to be certain that the unlock-state is properly propagated the server.

For the moment we are using Direct Methods, but there are concerns regarding what happens when the call times out. As we understand it if the server times out but the device successfully responds (getting an MQTT PUBACK from the IoT-Hub), then we have an inconsistency where the device is "unlocked" but the server think it failed. This is a state we want to avoid and it's important that the device and server are in synch.

Are there any good patterns how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, please don't worry about this issue. Direct methods represent a request-reply interaction with a device similar to an HTTP call in that they succeed or fail immediately (after a user-specified timeout). This approach is useful for scenarios where the course of immediate action is different depending on whether the device was able to respond.Direct methods are synchronous and either succeed or fail after the timeout period (default: 30 seconds, settable up to 3600 seconds). But it is no guarantee on ordering or any concurrency semantics on method calls.

Comment: I share you opinion, but my customer doesn't share it unfortunately. They have asked us to explore Twins (probably Module twins?) and optimistic concurrency with Etag. But that is explicitly stated in the docs not to use for two-way communication.

Comment: @Kimmen Sorry for my late reply. I think your customer is asked you to use [Device Twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins). Device Twin synchronizes the state of long-running workflows between device app and back-end app.

Comment: There's something called Module Twins as well (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-module-twins). But according to the docs, it's not recommended to use Device Twin in this way, also it's has much stricter throttling limit.

Comment: @Kimmen, sorry for late response.Module identity and module twin provides the same capabilities as device identity and device twin but at a finer granularity. They are very similar.In your scenario, device twin is sufficient.And what is the meaning of two-way communication as you mentioned? Does it mean bidirectional?

Comment: We have a scenario where the device can change a state, but cannot reverse the state without human interaction. Ex: the device can release a spring but a human has to rewind it back. So there's a concern that the cloud and the device are out of sync if the direct method times out; the cloud doesn't know if the state was changed or not. So the idea from the customer is to use a 2-phase-commit protocol to ensure the sync of state and using device twin to achieve that.

Comment: They are hoping that the $version property would help them here, but they havent understood the documentation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

We are going to rethink how we see the timeout and embrace uncertainty in this case. If we timeout we will think that as inconclusive and wait for next telemetry data from the device to be conclusive.

Comment: I think device twin is recommended for this case.The IoT platform will ensure that the state of the physical device matches its corresponding digital twin. Even if the device is offline when the command is sent from the application, the platform will sync the state when the device connects the next time. This functionality reduces the burden on the developers by providing an intelligent state machine for all the connected devices.